# How to call filter function js in blazor Asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

How to call filter function JavaScript in blazor server-side
I am using Blazor server-side with Asp.net core I don't know how to call this script to my page.razor in @code{}

```
<script> $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() { 
     var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); $("#myTable tr").filter(function(){ 
       $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) }); }); });
</script>
```

Comment: Please avoid adding images , instead add the code

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>

Comment: You may want to consider adding some more context to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Index.razor

```cs
@page "/"

@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="Test">Test</button>
@Result

@code
{

    private bool Result { get; set; } = false;
    private async Task Test()
    {
        Result = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("Test.testFunc");
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BlazorApp3</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>
    var Test = new function () {
        this.testFunc = function () {
            console.log("testFunc");
            return true;
        };
    };
    </script>
</body>
```

You can check that source code for more Javascript for Blazor https://github.com/ShadyNagy/Blazor.JavaScriptUtilities